# Помогите с discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пытаюсь создать голосовой канал через discord бота на python.
Испоьзую create_voice_channel, но постоянно выводятся ошибки что ничего такого нету. Пробовал и через bot.create_voice_channel, и использовал класс. Уже замучался, как можно создать голосовой канал. Я новичок, так что не судите строго.
Обновлено: надо создавать канал не через команду в чате а через событие on_voice_state_update, а там насколько я знаю нельзя передать аргумент ctx.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import config
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    #если пользователь зашёл в нужный канал
    if after.channel.id == 709163351820861450:
        await creat_voice_channel('test')
bot.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Желательно добавить код, которым вы пытались воспользоваться

Comment: Там просто куча кода который я уже и сам понять не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
PREFIX = '!'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def new_voice(ctx, name):
    await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name)
    # отчёт об успешном создании канала. Можно убрать, если отчёт в чате не нужен
    await ctx.send(f'Канал {name} успешно создан.') 

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Upd

Если вы используете `on_voice_update`, вы из параметра `member` можете достать `guild`, поскольку `member` - профиль пользователя на конкретном сервере, а не в дискорде вообще

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import randint

TOKEN = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
PREFIX = '!'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    # генерация псевдослучайного имени канала
    name = chr(randint(65, 123))
    while randint(0, 15):
        name += chr(randint(65, 123))

    # Создаём канал с этим именем. Отчёт отправляем пользователю в лс
    await member.guild.create_voice_channel(name) # нужная вам строка
    await member.send(f'Вы изменили состояние голосового канала. Это привело к созданию канала {name}')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно как то без ctx? Просто я делаю не через команду, а через событие on_voice_state_update. А там насколько я знаю нельзя передать ctx в качестве аргумента

Comment: @mihabarinov приведите в своём вопросе свой код

Comment: Заработало, спасибо Вам огромное). А то уже целый день мучался